# Android emulator can't connect to the internet

Tags: android, dns, emulation, android-browser, internet-connection

I'm running Mac OS (10.10.5) connecting to the internet via WIFI and have installed the Android SDK, Genymotion, BlueStacks, and Xamarin. On each emulator I have the same problem - I open the Android browser and can't connect to any webpage. I've tried running the emulator from the command line and setting the DNS server to 8.8.8.8 but to no avail:

```
./emulator -avd nexus9-4_4 -dns-server 8.8.8.8
```

Any suggestions? I just want to be able to easily test web pages on Android devices. Thanks.

[image: screenshot]